# How to write a method with a class as a parameter

Tags: java, parameters

I'm writing a compulsory assignment for my java class, we have a prepared method that must be coded to make a MST of a Graph. In the prepared method it's using another class as a parameter, and I'm wondering how i can implement this parameter into my code.

prepared code:

```
    public <T, E extends Comparable<E>> ArrayList<Edge<T>> mst(WeightedGraph<T, E> g) {

    }
```

WeightedGraph: another class in the compulsory file

T: the type of vertices

E: the type of edges

Now lets say i wanted to write:

```
if(T > 10)
     do something
```

How would i do that, how can i reference T or E or other methods from "WeightedGraph"?

Comment: By examining the WeightedGraph class, or at least its documentation, to learn what public methods it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing (or your teacher want you to do) is writing a generic method that determines a MST of a given graph. The given graph
is an instance of a generic class named WeightedGraph<T,E>. Because you didn't provide details about the class WeightedGraph<E,T> so my guess is
that this class is kind of a collection of vertices type T and edges type E and some methods for you to handle the graph.
Now answering your question:
How would you do this:

```
if(T > 10)
    do something;
```

No, you can't do this. T is a type, not a variable or a value to compare. What you can do here is:

```
if(g.getVertexCount() > 10 )
    do something;
```

For the question 'how can i reference T or E or other methods from "WeightedGraph"?',
I'm not sure if I understand this question clearly but you can call methods from the instance g of class WeightedGraph. Below is an example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Graph {
public <T, E extends Comparable<E>> ArrayList<Edge<T>> mst(WeightedGraph<T, E> g) {
    if(g.getVertexCount() > 10) {
        // do something
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Now you can use the code as follow:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Graph graph = new Graph();
        WeightedGraph<Long, Integer> wg = new WeightedGraph<>();
        List<Edge<Long>> result = graph.mst(wg);
        // do something with the result
    }
}
```

With code above, I've created a graph in which each vertex is a Long, and each edge is an Integer.